# How can I stub a method that takes a Generic class as a param?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a class under test that needs to stub out a call on a dependent class. The code that needs to be stubbed looks like this:

```
public class A {
 ...
 public void methodThatNeedsToBeStubbed(GenericClass genericClass){
    ...
 }
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
when(mockA.methodThatNeedsToBeStubbed(any(GenericClass<SomeDifferentClass>))
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work with a generic class as a param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an `ArgumentCaptor` with `@Captor`.

```
 @Captor
 ArgumentCaptor<GenericClass<SomeDifferentClass>> captor;

 @Before
 public void setup(){ MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this));}

 @Test
 public void test(){
   when(mockA.methodThatNeedsToBeStubbed(captor.capture()))...
 }
```